# Values of mongoose created object returning undefined in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I have a method to register users. I need to return the created object's email and name. something like object.name or object.email but I got undefined. But console.log(object) will actually console log the created object. But I dont understand why I cannot access object.name. nothing here has been able to solve the issue

```
async register(createDTO: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
        const { email } = createDTO;
        const user = await this.userModel.findOne({ email })

        if (user) {
            throw new HttpException('User already exists', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        const createdUser = new this.userModel(createDTO);
        var newUser = await createdUser.save();

        console.log("newUser email =", newUser.Email);

        console.log("createdUser email =", createdUser.Email);

        return this.sanitizeUser(createdUser);
    }
```

In the above code the console log gave this

```
newUser email = undefined
createdUser email = undefined
```

I don't understand why that is happening. I need to get the email and name back after it has been created in the db.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The User interface which extends Document are all in capslock. I changed it to small letters and I was able to access the values